# WPF - Freeze the first item in WPF nested ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, datatemplate

I have a ListView which contains a text block and a ListView in it as Data template. Below is my code.

```
<ListView x:Name="DoctorsList" Grid.Column="1"  VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DoctorName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AppointmentDetails}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="2 2 0 0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PatientName}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

[image]

Here, I want to freeze the doctor name in the top of the list while the user scroll down. Now the doctor name is hidden if the scrolls down. My goal is if the user scrolls down, the patients names only need to be scrolled. The doctor's name has to be freeze in the top. So that the user can view the complete patients list with the respective doctor without confusion. Please help.

Comment: You could make the ListView with the patients a fixed height. But that would probably look pretty ugly.

Comment: Maybe you should transform your data into a table where the doctors are column headers. Actually, `ListView` looks like a strange choice of control for this functionality.

Comment: @Marc It will give scroll bar for every column. Yup its look ugly and occupies more space.

Comment: @MathivananKP If you do not want to change your entire layout, you can use a third ListView which only has the doctors. So you have one ListView with only the doctor names and a ListView which only has the ListViews of the patients as children.

Comment: @Marc Tried this another list view method. Its some what satisfied my requirement. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows how you could translate the structure to a `ListView` with `GridView` where each column is a doctor.

Supposing a source data structure like the following:

```
public class DoctorsVM
{
    public DoctorsVM()
    {
        Doctors = new List<Doctor>();
    }
    public ICollection<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }
}

public class Doctor
{
    public Doctor()
    {
        AppointmentDetails = new List<AppointmentDetail>();
    }
    public string DoctorName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AppointmentDetail> AppointmentDetails { get; set; }
}

public class AppointmentDetail
{
    public string PatientName { get; set; }
}
```

You can create the following conversion:

```
public class DoctorAppointmentCollectionVM
{
    public DoctorAppointmentCollectionVM()
    {
        Doctors = new List<Doctor>();
        Entries = new List<DoctorAppointmentLineItem>();
    }

    public List<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }

    public List<DoctorAppointmentLineItem> Entries { get; set; }
}
public class DoctorAppointmentLineItem
{
    public DoctorAppointmentLineItem()
    {
        AppointmentLine = new List<AppointmentDetail>();
    }

    public List<AppointmentDetail> AppointmentLine { get; set; }
}


public DoctorAppointmentCollectionVM DoctorsToLineCollection(DoctorsVM docs)
{
    var result = new DoctorAppointmentCollectionVM();

    for (int i = 0; i < docs.Doctors.Count; i++)
    {
        var doc = docs.Doctors.ElementAt(i);
        result.Doctors.Add(doc);
        for (int j = 0; j < doc.AppointmentDetails.Count; j++)
        {
            var appointment = doc.AppointmentDetails.ElementAt(j);
            DoctorAppointmentLineItem patientArray;
            if (j >= result.Entries.Count)
            {
                patientArray = new DoctorAppointmentLineItem();
                patientArray.AppointmentLine.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, docs.Doctors.Count).Select(x => (AppointmentDetail)null));
                result.Entries.Add(patientArray);
            }
            else
            {
                patientArray = result.Entries[j];
            }
            patientArray.AppointmentLine[i] = appointment;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And create a listview as follows:

```
<ListView x:Name="lv1" ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}" Loaded="lv1_Loaded">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="gv1">
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

With the loaded event to create a column for each doctor

```
private void lv1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var data = lv1.DataContext as DoctorAppointmentCollectionVM;
    if (data != null)
    {
        gv1.Columns.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Doctors.Count; ++i)
        {
            gv1.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
            {
                Header = data.Doctors[i].DoctorName,
                DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(string.Format("AppointmentLine[{0}].PatientName", i)),
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes a static set of data, you would need to add more logic if the data are supposed to change dynamically after initial loading.